# How to create line with exact same length over and over again?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, polyline-creation, line, length

I need to draw 30 meter lines in specific places. Ctrl+l is too annoying to do everytime. Is there a easy way to define specific same length for a line that I need to draw many times?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to create a [fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002q000000) grid specific to your area of interest.  By specifying one row and X columns, you can very efficiently create a series of lines.  I describe this method in greater detail [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/46966/8104) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/46935/8104) for two similar situations.  For fine control of individual line placement, use the editor.  From the image, you can see I created 16 lines with the fishnet tool and moved/rotated them in an editing session.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you can make the start of the line as coordinate locations in a table, then [Add Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Add_Field/001700000047000000/) and [Calculate Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) values for the end coordinate locations (if the 30 m change is in both the X and Y or by an angle this may need trigonometry), then [Make XY Event Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Make_XY_Event_Layer/00170000006z000000/) for each set of coordinate pairs, [Merge](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Merge/001700000055000000/) into one point file, and then use [Points To Line](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Points_To_Line/00170000003s000000/) with the common ID field for the Line_Field parameter, then you will have all lines drawn automatically.